# Is it possible to change the field length of a shapefile to over 254?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, limitations

The maximum field length for a shapefile is 254 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Limitations) and because of this I'm having problems with the input attributes, which have a size greater than 254.

What alternatives are there for having longer field lengths?

Comment: Cathrin, accepting any good answers to your previous questions helps us know what has worked and what has not. This will encourage people to answer your questions in the future.  Please take a moment to review your other questions and, if you can, accept answers to some of them.

Answer (score 13):

That's [one of the many limitations of the Shapefile format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Limitations), imposed by the DBF format.

Consider using PostGIS to store your data and attributes, where the lengths of text fields are virtually unlimited.<sup>*</sup>

__

<sup>* The maximum field size for PostgreSQL is 1 GB, so the limit is a billion characters.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As written in other answers, this is a limitation of the Shapefile format. Consider switching to a different format unless you really need to exchange data with someone who insists on shapefiles.

For an outline of this and other limitations of shapefiles, and an overview of alternative formats, see http://switchfromshapefile.org/

**For individual use, usually GeoPackage (gpkg) is the best alternative.**

[I stumbled across this many years later as a "related question" to something else on gis.stackexchange. Adding this since there are better alternatives that have developed in the nearly 10 years since the Q was posed and answered. Unfortunately, shapefiles -- and their limitations -- continue to still be in use.]

Answer (score 1):

If you have Microsoft Access, you can create a Memo field in a table for your data requiring > 255 characters, populate the table, and then in QGIS join your Shapefile to the mdb table.